# Scala support in a maven project

Tags: scala, maven

I've found a guide to add scala support to a maven project in this link -> http://stuq.nl/weblog/2008-11-26/4-steps-to-add-scala-to-your-maven-java-projects

However, the repositories doesn't exist anymore.

Is there anoter way to add scala support to a maven project? How can can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala Tools is no more.

Instead try using the [scala-maven-plugin](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin):

From their documentation, here is what is needed to get started:

```
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Sonatype's repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public) and `net.alchim31.maven` for `scala-maven-plugin` `groupId`instead.